# Create new active record object with relationship?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I understand you can do something like this:

```
# Payment belongs_to Product 
# Product has_many Payments
product_id = Product.find_by_name("widget").id
Payment.new(product_id: product_id)
```

This works, but is it possible to do something like this?

```
Payment.new(product: {name: "widget})
```

This throws an error, but perhaps my syntax is just off? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going wrong way, consider this

```
product = Product.where(name: "widget").first
product.payments.new # payment will have correct product_id automatically
```

Comment: I'd add that if the OP is after prettier code, then he should also consider incorporating `find_by` or `find_by_name`, depending on the Rails version, rather than `where(conditions).first`

Comment: Thanks @Humza for the suggestion (+1). I implemented into the question.

Comment: I don't know that this is simpler, but it's an interesting approach. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @newUserNameHere the second line returns `payment` object, not a `product`, why would you select `.last` afterwards?

Comment: @newUserNameHere if you are about one-liners, just use `Product. find_by_name('widget').payments.new(your_options)`. I prefer clearer code, rather than shorter.